Define pina store that takes argument as to make a closure
I need to define a Pinia store in Vue 3 - I'm doing this to pass a user into the store so I can use it in the store methods, creating a closure so that I can create > 1 of this store instance with different users:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import {getOptionsDoc} from "../data_service";

export const useOptionsStore = (user) => defineStore('options', () => {
  const options = getOptionsDoc(user)
  return { options }
})()

This seems like not the right way to do it, even though it works. I want to make sure that I don't create multiple calls to getOptionsDoc and that I use the ones already fetched if I use this store in > 1 component.
Is this the right way to do this? I cannot seem to find an idiomatic way to do this.

"I don't create multiple calls to getOptionsDoc" - there's only one call per pinia instance. It's unknown what's the intention and how right the way is. Generally there's no reason to extract store body to separate function

I don't understand what you mean...

Consider explaining your case further for more specific answer. It's unknown how and why you use useOptionsStore, and why you created getOptionsDoc

Neither of those is the point. The point is I'm trying to create a store that needs to take a user as a parameter and create a closure with it. There's other stuff that the store does (this is a minimal example) but all of that is irrelevant to the question...

Unless you know an answer to your own question, other users may have an idea about the point. You're asking about the right way to do something without giving enough info on "something". What's the point? Basically, if useOptionsStore  is used to create a finite amount of stores like useAdminStore = useOptionsStore('admin') then it's ok but there's probably a better way to write this. If user is dynamic value fetched from somewhere and you call useOptionsStore inside a component then it's not ok
